# Query to select distinct values of a column and count them, but also detail them by another column

Tags: sql, oracle

Basiclly how to turn this

| Type | Subtype | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | S1 | string1 |
| A | S2 | string1 |
| A | S2 | string1 |
| A | S2 | string1 |
| A | S3 | string1 |
| A | S3 | string1 |

into this

| Type | Notes | Details |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | string1 | S1 (1), S2 (3), S3(2) |

is it even possible?

In oracle, I've been going about it with SELECT DISTINCTs and GROUP BYs, some JOINS but I'm not really getting what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate twice:

```sql
SELECT type,
       notes,
       LISTAGG(subtype || ' (' || num_subtypes || ')', ', ')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY subtype) AS details
FROM   (
  SELECT type,
         notes,
         subtype,
         COUNT(*) AS num_subtypes
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY type, notes, subtype
)
GROUP BY type, notes
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (Type, Subtype, Notes) AS
SELECT 'A', 'S1', 'string1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'S2', 'string1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'S2', 'string1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'S2', 'string1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'S3', 'string1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'S3', 'string1' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| TYPE | NOTES | DETAILS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | string1 | S1 (1), S2 (3), S3 (2) |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/esS9fbut)

Comment: Absolutely beautiful, thank you very much! xoxo